# Object get of JSONObject returns a number that should be double as an int

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I am receiving information from a server and I obtain several values from a JSONArray, for a partyicular it is as follows:

... "precioCompra":0.00,".... (Body)

But when I extract that value, an exception occurs indicating that one is trying to write an integer number on a Double variable.

Analyzing more deeply how is the process of extracting the value of the body, I can verify when the number doesn't have a fractional part becomes integer and there the problem happens, please look at the image.

[image]

If the number has a fractional part, there is no problem, for example:

..."precioCompra":2.98... (Body)

The way I recover that value and store it is like this:

```js
 productoServicioObtenido.setPrecioVenta((double) item.get("precioVenta"));
```

Where:

```js
...
double precioVenta;
...
public void setPrecioVenta(double precioVenta){this.precioVenta = precioVenta;}
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Why write `(double) item.get()` instead of `item.getDouble()` ?

Comment: Ok. It works. I was modifying a preexisting example. Thanks for your help.